# How to set layout_width as WRAP_CONTENT to ConstraintLayout programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I want to programmatically set Width as WRAP_CONTENT to constraint layout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/asdA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

I am not able to do so, I've searched in stack but just able to do it.
Using Kotlin!

Comment: what type of layout you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
asdA.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

**Option 2:**

```
    val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
   .asdA?.setLayoutParams(params)
```

Comment: Erg, Thanks.
This was very simple..